# Probability of the intersection of two sets.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $(\Omega, F, P)$ be a probability space and let $A, B$ contained in the sigma algebra $F$.

Is it true that
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)$$ implies $$A\subseteq B?$$.

Thank you very much

Comment: You might be able to phrase something close to what you hoped correctly if you include a phrase like "*up to a [null set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_set)*"

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And can I say that $P(A \cap C)=P(B\cap C)$, for any measurable set $C$?

Comment: I wanted to say $P(A\cup B\cup C)=P(A\cup C)$

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily, no.

What it DOES mean is that $B\setminus A$ -- that is, the possible outcomes which ARE in $B$ but ARE NOT in $A$ -- has $P(B\setminus A)=0$.

For example, take $\Omega=[0,1]$, with $\mathcal{F}$ and $P$ being the Lebesgue $\Sigma$-algebra and the corresponding Lebesgue measure.

Let $A=[0,\frac{1}{2}]$, and $B=[0,\frac{1}{2}]\cup\{\frac{2}{3}\}$.  In this case, your condition is satisfied, but it is definitely not the case that $B\subseteq A$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. And can I say that $P(A \cap C)=P(B\cap C)$, for any measurable set $C$?

Comment: Yep.  Write $B\cap C=(A\dot{\cup} (B\setminus A))\cap C=(A\cap C)\dot{\cup}((B\setminus A)\cap C)$, where $\dot{\cup}$ indicates disjoint union.  The latter set is a subset of $B\setminus A$, which we know has measure $0$.